# Oversampling using SMOTE leading to bad predictions on test set

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, oversampling, smote

I have a dataset with an imbalanced binary target. One class accounts for about 94 % of the target variable. I used SMOTE to oversample the minority class but after the oversampling step when I train a Random Forest on the oversampled data and make predictions on the test set, it predicts the minority class for the whole test set. I can't seem to figure out where things went wrong or what the problem could be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oversampling is a completely invalid statistical technique and represents a misunderstanding of proper accuracy scoring rules.  See for example [this](http://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage).

Comment: Have you tried another oversampling technique? What is your classifier's response to the training set? Is the final distribution around 50 %? And, are you certain that you trained and validated your classifier well with other hyper-parameters? Might worth to try another classifier btw just to see if you suffer from the same problem .

Comment: Why not consider the possibility that the best prediction is indeed whichever class accounts for 94% of the target regardless of your features - something you won't discover if you oversample?